# Configuration of custom Log4j appender doesn't work

Tags: solr, log4j, jetty

I have created a custom appender (will be used for Linux). For creating of this appender I used this article [How write custom log4j appender](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073104/learn-java/write-custom-appenders-for-log4j.html)

```
public class SolrAppender extends AppenderSkeleton {

private String path = null;     
public void setPath(String path)  { this.path = path; }
public String  getPath()          { return this.path; }

@Override
public boolean requiresLayout() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void close() {

}

@Override
public void activateOptions() {
    super.activateOptions();        
}

@Override
public synchronized void append(LoggingEvent event) {

            SolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer(path);                   
    SolrInputDocument document = new SolrInputDocument();
    //some logic
            UpdateResponse response = server.add(document);
    server.commit();                

}
```

Configuration of this appender is

1. # Solr appender
2. log4j.appender.SOLR = ricardo.solr.appender.QueryParser.SolrAppender
3. log4j.appender.SOLR.layout = org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout
4. log4j.appender.SOLR.path = http://XX.XXX.XX.XX:8985/application/core

Appender works correct if path is hardcoded. Why path is not set via configuration?

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen so far, the name of a property of an appender, in the configuration, should start with an upper case character, so 'Path' instead of 'path', so you should use:

```
log4j.appender.SOLR.Path = http://XX.XXX.XX.XX:8985/application/core
```

Not sure why it's not the case for 'layout', though.

Comment: Changes Path to path didn't help.